# Copy string to clipboard after button click

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, clipboard

My Discord bot should copy a string to my clipboard after a button is clicked. The interaction fails everytime:

```
import clipboard
from discord_components import Button, DiscordComponents

@client.command()
async def command(ctx, *args):
    # do some stuff
    await ctx.send('message', components=[Button(label='Copy to clipboard', custom_id="copy_btn")])

@client.event
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    if interaction.custom_id == 'copy_btn':
        try:
            print('try to copy string')
            clipboard.copy('my string')
            await ctx.send('string copied')
        except Exception as e:
            print('failed to copy string to clipboard\n' + e)
```

My bot sends me a message with a button when using `command`. Clicking that button prints `try to copy string` into my console, but 'my string' is not copied. There is no exception beeing raised.

`pip install clipboard` was successful.
Same for `pip install discord-components`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issues here other than that there might potentially be some deep misunderstanding here: your code interacts with clipboard of the machine that is running the bot, not the client that clicks the button - discord does not provide any such capability.

You should be able to easily tell if it worked properly by changing the call to `send` in the `try` block to

```py
await ctx.send(clipboard.paste())
```

Comment: ah yes, that makes sense. It gets copied to my host machine, which runs the bot